# set parameter to be required in symfony2 routing

Tags: validation, symfony, parameters, routes

Long story short, I have a form for which I want the id field to be mandatory and also a number. Based on the symfony2 book, this should be easily achieved by the following routing:

```
acme_demo_users_save:
    pattern:  /userSave
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:User:save, _format: ~ }
    requirements:
        _method: POST
        id: \d+
```

the method requirement is indeed checked as it throws an error if I try to perform a get. However, no type of parameter validation is performed. I can submit the form with or without id.

Am i missing something? Are parameters validated only for GET?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This route doesnt know how to get ID parameter. Edit its pattern as below:

```
acme_demo_users_save:
    pattern: /userSave/{id}
    ...
```

So the url will look like http://mysite.com/userSave/12 (12 is id)

If you need to submit ID by post request just add validation constraint to the form and omit id validation in the route